# Using Advance Rest API for IPN in localhost

Tags: rest, api, magento, paypal, paypal-ipn

i have read that in in able to test IPN in localhost magento site ,i can use Advance Rest API in google chrome ,now i downloaded already the app and test some values, but it showed The response was Empty..

[image]

how to test it correctly? am i doing the right thing there in the picture above? thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test IPN on your localhost, as IPN is all about PayPal's server initiating a server-side POST to a URL you define.

As a result, your IPN script must be accessible by the outside world (or you can use a tunnel such as ngrok.me/localtunnel.me)

You can test on localhost using ngrok :- https://ngrok.com/
Simply run ngrok locally then paste test url that ngrok gives you (something like http://1bc7d09d.ngrok.com/)
It provides a tunnel to your localhost.

More information visit this URL :-[Paypal Sandbox Test Tool IPN Simulator in Localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469636/paypal-sandbox-test-tool-ipn-simulator-in-localhost)