# How Do You Use PayPal Express Checkout in XAMPP?

Tags: xampp, localhost, paypal

I am hosting a website using XAMPP. The website uses PayPal API for Express Checkout. If I move the website to a real hosted server (i.e. www.website.com), the PayPal checkout system will work. If I use it from XAMPP (localhost), it won't even connect to PayPal. How would I make this work from my localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Port forwarding. Your router has a public ip (not 127.0.0.1) Configure your router to accept requests from the interwebs.

Step 2. Have a spare domain name? Configure your domain @ your registar: Point "A" Record to your newly forwarded IP.

Step 3. Add a fake HTTPS cert http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem to the root folder of your XAMPP installation.

Not the end-all, say, all-a guideline. Tricky, but a starting point.

With this approach, you can test Paypal IPN's, use the sandbox, all the good stuff, as well as monkey around with all the other major vendors' api's on your local server.

Answer (score 0):

These links will be helpful for you.

http://demos.ipn-easy.com/Howto/TestEnvironment.aspx

[Can I test paypal api's from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510995/can-i-test-paypal-apis-from-localhost)